# Handle KeyDown and KeyUp events triggering with arrow buttons on keyboard in WinForms desktop application

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown, keyup

I'm trying to figure out, how to handle `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events triggering with arrow buttons on keyboard in `WinForms` `C#` desktop application, instead using the `button1`:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     y = y - 10; // Go up
     moveGraphicObject();
 }
```

but if I use arrow keys, events does not fires with or without other controls on form:

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
       x = x - 10;
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
       x = x + 10;
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
       y = y - 10;
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
       y = y + 10;   
    }   
    
    moveGraphicObject();
 }
```

Comment: Override [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method of your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out **PreviewKeyDown** event. MSDN has a pretty good example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

> By default, KeyDown does not fire for the ARROW keys PreviewKeyDown is
> where you preview the key. Do not put any logic here, instead use the
> KeyDown event after setting IsInputKey to true.

Comment: link only answers aren't overly useful and links may break over time, always best to include the relevant section in your answer